# How connect to WAN by ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh

I try connect to my PC by WAN ip address, but I get message about `ssh: connect to host arch port 22: Connection refused`. I add my WAN ip address into `/etc/hosts` file. By the way, I use Arch Linux. In `/etc/hosts` I add next line `**.***.**.*** arch`, where `arch` is name of my host(pc).

Notice, as I know my internet provider locked 22 port, could this be the reason?

Comment: If you're 100% certain that your ISP has blocked port 22, then you will not be able to get it to work unless you move ports. Have you port forwarded (if necessary)?

Comment: I changed port on 2222, but I get same message again.
Where I can check have I port forwarding? If you mean AllowAgentForwarding, AllowTcpForwarding and GatewayPorts I use it by parameter `yes`.

Comment: Does the WAN address actually belong to your computer, or does it belong to your router?

Comment: If you've got a router that uses NAT, you must forward traffic on the port you specify so that it makes it through the router and to the correct machine on the internal network. That option is on the router itself.

Comment: @user1686, it belong to my router.

Comment: @SamForbis, how I can confirm that my route use NAT? And it's truth, how I can forward traffic.

Comment: Any router that assigns local IP addresses uses NAT. You'll need to reference your router's manual for instructions on how to set up port forwarding.

Comment: i'm afraid I can't handle it.